# Some mistakes in the language

Tags: dart

I'm new in Dart, I want to precise this. I create two classes in Dart, one is 'Person' and the other one is a child of the first one, and it's named 'Employee'.
I create an object of Person. When I change this object to an Instance of class Employee, nothing wrong. But at the time that I'm asking to a parameter that is inside the Employee, I raised an error.

So why Dart allow me to the class of the object, but not allowed me to access to a parameter inside the new class?

The code below :

```
void main {
var person = Person(name: "Zozor");
  print(person.describe());
  person = Employee(taxCode: 'AAB');
  person.sayName();
  print(person.taxCode);
}

class Person {
  Person({this.name, this.age, this.height});
  String name;
  final int age;
  final double height;
  String describe() => "Hello, I'm ${this.name}. I'm ${this.age} and I'm ${this.height} meter${this.height == 1 ? '':'s'} tall";
  void sayName()=> print("Hello, I'm ${this.name}.");
}

class Employee extends Person {
  Employee({String name, int age, double height, this.taxCode, this.salary}) : super(name:name, age: age, height: height);
  final String taxCode;
  final int salary;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables in Dart must be declared before being used.  They have a type and store a reference to the value (see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_variables.htm).

```
var person = Person(name: "Zozor");
```

Declares the variable person of type Person (type is derived from the type of class it is initialized to).

When you assign:

```
person = Employee(taxCode: 'AAB');
```

The type is unchanged with the assignment (i.e. remains Person), only the reference changes to the result of downcasting the Employee to a Person (the downcasting is done implicitly as described https://news.dartlang.org/2012/05/types-and-casting-in-dart.html).

The above is due to var creating static type variables.
An alternative would be to use dynamic typing as in:

```
dynamic person = Person(name: "Zozor");
```

This declares a person variables whose type is dynamic.  Now when the assignment is made to Employee:

```
person = Employee(taxCode: 'AAB');
```

The type of the person variable is now Employee rather than Person.  Furthermore, there is no downcasting of Employee and no error message related to taxCode.

A simple way to stay with static (rather than using dynamic) is to use an explicit recasting of person to Employee:

```
print((person as Employee).taxCode);
```

This casts a person to Employee then gets the taxCode.

Comment: Ok, I see the trick. In Dart, unlike you specifies dynamic to a variable, the class of a object never changes.

Comment: Correct.  Dart static typing provides compiler and IDE coding advantages such as https://hackernoon.com/statically-typed-vs-dynamically-typed-languages-e4778e1ca55

Comment: But if we downcast an object, what will be the purpose of it if you cannot use the downcast class methods or properties. Hum, I think _'dynamic'_ keyword is too heavy to simply downcast an object.

Comment: @Charles-LéviBRIANI I believe I addressed this in my updated answer.  Basically you can get access by recasting i.e. (person As Employee).taxCode

Comment: Thanks ! It is a better way this "as" keyword.